# How to write memory of a dll?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

I'm trying to replace a specific string in memory belongs to a dll. Here's the code.

I can read it, and it gives me correct result, but when writing VC++ shows 'Access violation writing location'.

```
HMODULE HMODULE1 = LoadLibrary(L"my.dll");

std::string x1(8, '\0');
std::string x2 = "CIFCDMEY";
auto startPos = (void*)((char*)(HMODULE1)+0x1158A0 + 9);
// Correct, I can read the memory
memcpy_s((void*)x1.data(), x1.size(), startPos, x1.size());
// Access violation writing location
memcpy_s(startPos, x2.size(), x2.data(), x2.size());


auto handle = GetCurrentProcess();
SIZE_T num;
auto ret = WriteProcessMemory(handle, startPos, x2.data(), x2.size(), &num);
auto lastError1 = GetLastError();
LPVOID lpMessageBuffer1 = NULL;
size_t size1 = ::FormatMessage(
    FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
    NULL,
    lastError1,
    MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
    (LPTSTR)&lpMessageBuffer1,
    0,
    NULL);
std::wstring errorMessage1;
if (size1 > 0) {
    // errorMessage1: Invalid access to memory location.
    errorMessage1 = std::wstring((LPCTSTR)lpMessageBuffer1, size1);
}
```

In 'Watch' window, the value of variable `startPos` is `my.dll!0x0f2a58a9 (load symbols for additional information)`.

I know people use 'WriteProcessMemory' to write memory of a process, how about a dll?

Comment: A DLL executes inside a process. So WriteProcessMemory applies. The other way, is to use VirtualProtect to change the protection to allow write access.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan LastError shows 'Invalid access to memory location'.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan VirtualProtect works.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan "*So WriteProcessMemory applies*" - except that in this case, the target process is the calling process, so `WriteProcessMemory` is not needed at all. The process has *direct* access to the DLL's memory.

Comment: @remy Sure. But WriteProcessMemory will take care of protection.

Answer (score 0):

If the target memory page does not have write permissions you need to take them using [VirtualProtect()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-virtualprotect)

I use a simple wrapper function for all my patching, it uses the PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE [memory protection constant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/memory-protection-constants) because if you are modifying a code page this will avoid crashes when the instruction pointer lands in the same memory page and you only used PAGE_READWRITE

```C++
void Patch(char* dst, char* src, const intptr_t size)
{
    DWORD oldprotect;

    VirtualProtect(dst, size, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &oldprotect);
    memcpy(dst, src, size);
    VirtualProtect(dst, size, oldprotect, &oldprotect);
}
```